# in php how we can use two keyword together

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Select 
  student_course_modules.module_id 
from 
  student_course_modules 
  left join student_courses on student_courses.id = student_course_modules.student_course_id 
where (
  student_courses.course_id="1" 
  And student_courses.student_id="ST_2014_1" 
  And where student_course_modules.module_id IN ("'1'")
)
```

> error:----#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'union where student_course_modules.module_id IN
>   ("'1'")) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: What is your question? There's no PHP here. You should *ask* a question instead of just posting all your SQL code.

Comment: The error message mentions `union` which is not in your SQL ?

Comment: Dumping an error message that's not related to the sql. Nice work.

Comment: And `IN ("'1'")` extraneous quotes?

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one WHERE clause in your query, but you can link the two conditions with the AND operator within that WHERE clause:

```
WHERE student_courses.course_id="1" 
AND student_courses.student_id="ST_2014_1"
AND student_course_modules.module_id IN ("'1'")
```

You Query should be terminated by a semicolon ";".
Your MySQL error does not match the query you have given, since the query does not contain a union.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```
Select student_course_modules.module_id from student_course_modules left join 
    student_courses on student_courses.id = student_course_modules.student_course_id  
where student_courses.course_id="1" 
  And student_courses.student_id="ST_2014_1" 
  And student_course_modules.module_id IN ("'1'"))
```